# How to restrict API access to only authorized domains using Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, cross-domain

I'm working on a layer of security for my Node.js/Express.js app where I would like restrict access to an `authlist` (authorized list) of domains.

> **NB** The opposite of an `authlist` is a `denylist`.

**The Rundown:**

- Users create a `Project` on my system.
- Each `Project` is issued a `Public Key` and `Secret Key` that will be used to create signed requests.
- Additionally, the admin of any given `Project` will need to supply a `authlist` of domains that they'd like to be able to access the API for that given `Project`. This is done in the web-based console, not as part of every request.
- When the API receives a request, `req.get('origin')` is used to determine the origin domain of the request.
- The origin is checked against the `authlist` and either allowed or denied accordingly.

**In Code**:

```
var app = require('express');

app.post('/my-api-endpoint', function(req,res) {

    var originDomain = req.get('origin');   /// e.g. mysite.com
    /// Origin is then checked against the authlist array of domains

});
```

**The Questions**

- What concerns do I need to be aware of with regard to Domain Origin
  Spoofing?
- Is this a worthy security feature at all? Or is it so easily spoofed that there's no point in bothering?

Comment: This might work for servers, but for servers you generally know the IP address so it's easier for you to use that. For clients there's no guarantee that the IP address you see will relate to the originating machine, or that it will resolve to a domain at all. That doesn't include any malicious activity that will further complicate things. This is probably not worth implementing.

Comment: I actually already have this implemented using an IP Whitelist, but the problem is that if I get a client that wants to host their app in an environment like an AWS Auto-Scaling-Group then they're not going to want to have to update the IP whitelist every time their app scales. Thanks for the info.

Comment: It seems to me like you should issue authentication credentials and regulate access to the API that way.  Then your clients can use whatever infrastructure they want and that's not your business.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yup, that's what I already have implemented with the `Public Key` and `Secret Key`. Origin whitelisting (by IP or domain) is a second layer of security that I wanted to implemented, but it seems this isn't going to be possible for a public-facing IP.

Comment: When you do you think you need more than the authentication you already have?  Just curious what that isn't enough?

Comment: Paranoia mostly. There are also 'silent alarms' implemented that would require time to respond to in certain situations. One scenario would be that an ex-employee still has access to a repo/codebase that may have the `Public Key` and `Secret Key` embedded but no access to the server running any given application. Without whitelisting either IP or Domain the ex-employee would be able to spin up a destructive app on any given server (con't)

Comment: With whitelisting, a silent alarm would be tripped and the admin on the `Project` would be emailed or otherwise alerted that an IP or Domain that has not been whitelisted has attempted to access the API for that `Project`. The disgruntled ex-employee would figure out pretty quickly that there's a whitelist to wrangle with, but time would pass in-between the silent alarm being tripped and the ex-employee figuring out how to gain access to a server that has been whitelisted. Thus, they would be caught in the meantime. Kinda like the double-doors for jewelry shops that trap would-be thieves.

Comment: I'm thinking I'll make this optional and the user can turn on IP Whitelisting if they have a server with a static IP.

Comment: @AJB req.get('origin') is not always defined as not all the browsers might not respect sending it, user might fake the origin in the header and not to mention req.get('origin') is undefined almost always over HTTPS/SSL which I a assuming you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish what you are looking for is to forget domains all-together and optionally allow the whitelisting of IP ranges. With that said, some of the biggest APIs in the world do not even use this security layer (i.e. eBay, Amazon's Marketplace, etc...).

In the interest in addressing the extra paranoia though, you could have your clients set up subnets to launch their autoscaling servers into which would give them a static range of IPs to whitelist. Then only servers inside this IP range would be given permission to access your endpoints.

Here is a question on AWS that explains a tad more about that:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=233469

Answer (score 0):

Its is possible to use the middleware feature to use something like you did in the question example, but origin, til I know, is a only browser feature, so it's possible to user a proxy to mask it and easely pass througth this kind of filter

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32677572)